# Where to set environment variables for app?

Tags: ios, xcode4, environment-variables, xcode4.6

I'm working with source code that is frozen and cannot be changed; but its ENV aware and expects changes through the ENV. The source code is being used in an Xcode 4/iOS project.

Xcode 3 allowed us to set environmental variables on the app in the Executable folder (see Figure 1 at [iOS Debugging Magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html)). Xcode 4 appears to lack the 'executable info' that was present in Xcode 3.

I've looked through a number of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but no one has answered the questions. Answers usually degenerate to preprocessor macros. Confer: [How to set environment variables in iPhone executable using XCode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295476/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-iphone-executable-using-xcode-4), [Conditional Environment Variables in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816136/condtional-environment-varialbes-in-xcode), and [Where to set environmental variables in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584089/where-to-set-environmental-variables-in-ios)?.

How does on set an app's environment variables in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can set environment variables via Xcode Schemes. To edit a scheme, select it in the top bar:

[image: Editing a scheme in Xcode]

Choose the Run mode and go to the Arguments tab, and there you go...

[image: Setting environment variables in Xcode]

By default, these settings are also used for the Test and Profile modes.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe it was so much trouble to find anyone else say this in my Google search results.

Comment: Will those variable be accessible when archiving the app for deployment to Test Flight ???

Comment: No – they are passed to the app when you launch the app from the selected scheme in Xcode, but do not become part of the app.