# sh: gnuplot: command not found in Gnuplot + Xcode

Tags: xcode, gnuplot

There was a similar question to mine however the answers were not quite solutions so if I could get some help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

The problem is that when I compile, Xcode gives the aforementioned error of sh: gnuplot: command not found.

I checked `which gnuplot` in terminal and as expected from macports it is in `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot`. Also `printf("PATH=%s\n", getenv("PATH"));` shows the path `PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` I suspect therein lies the problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace occurrences of `gnuplot`, in your script, with `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot` to take `$PATH` out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue to prevent Xcode from running is indeed related to `PATH` of `gnuplot`. Depending on which package management system you use in mac, the directory of `gnuplot` can vary.

Typing `which gnuplot` in terminal will show the exact location of `gnuplot`.

In the case of `macport`, `gnuplot` is located in `/opt/local/bin`, which is not included in the default path setting of Xcode.

To check your `PATH`, typing

```
std::cout << "PATH=" << getenv("PATH") << std::endl; // #include<iostream>
```

or

```
printf( "PATH=%s\n", getenv("PATH") ); // #include<cstdio>
```

can show you a likewise path as

> `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin`

---

Here is my solution.

1. The easiest way is to use a soft link to combine the real directory (`/opt/local/bin`) of `gnuplot` with the acceptable direction, such as ( `/usr/bin` ) that shows from `getenv("PATH")` in Xcode, like
   `ln -s /opt/local/bin/gnuplot /usr/bin/gnuplot`
2. If your `.bash_profile` setting resists the previous method, then the safer and more stable method is to adding an external path in Xcode project directly, 
   which is original from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393053/where-to-set-environment-variables-for-app). In brief, add `PATH` in `Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme...` as shown below before closing this window.

[image]

Try this code to generate your first ever gnuplot in Xcode

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

int main( ) {
    Gnuplot gp;
    gp << "plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))\n";
    return 0;
}
```