# gnuplot won't work - sh gnuplot: command not found

Tags: c, gnuplot, xcode7.3

I am trying to use `gnuplot` directly from my C application under MacOSX in combination with Xcode. I downloaded the appropriate source files `gnuplot_i.h` and `gnuplot_i.c` (from [here](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/), version `gnuplot_i-2.11`) and included the header file. This all compiles just fine. I also checked if I had the newest version installed, which I appear to have:

```
[mycomputer:projectfolder]Me $ brew upgrade gnuplot
Error: gnuplot 5.0.3 already installed
```

In my application I just tried to use a simple example from the Documentation page ([this one](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/index.html)). The output is simply

> sh: gnuplot: command not found

```
gnuplot_ctrl * g = gnuplot_init();

gnuplot_cmd(g, "set terminal png"); /* this outputs "sh: gnuplot: command not found" */
gnuplot_cmd(g, "set output \"/Users/Me/.../log/sine.png\"");
gnuplot_plot_equation(g, "sin(x)", "Sine wave");
gnuplot_close(g);
```

Does anyone have an idea, what could be the cause of the problem? I never used gnuplot before but I would love to. Right now I always need to write to a file and plot using MATLAB...
I already read some posts here and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815583/sh-gnuplot-command-not-found-in-gnuplot-xcode) might have a solution, but I am not sure how to replace the path in `gnuplot_cmd()` or if that's possible in the first place.

Does it have something to do with the fact that I am not on a Linux machine?

Thanks in advance :)

**edit** gnuplot is installed here:

```
[mycomputer:projectfolder]Me$ brew ls gnuplot
/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.3/bin/gnuplot
/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.3/libexec/gnuplot/5.0/gnuplot_x11
/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.3/share/gnuplot/ (36 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.3/share/man/ (2 files)
```

Comment: Have you checked *where* the `gnuplot` command is installed? Maybe it's not in the standard path?

Comment: I updated my question, thanks for the hint. I suspect the `Cellar` is not the standard path?

Comment: It most definitely isn't. :) So you either have to modify `gnuplot_i.c` to use an absolute path in the `gnuplot_init` function (in the call to `popen`), or make a symbolic link placed in a standard directory, or add the `/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.3/bin` directory to the path.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That worked! Thanks a bunch! Make an actual answer out of this if you want, I will accept it ;)