# Write the XCode output into a file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, ios7

I would like that the XCode output (from NSLog() or whatever) is **automatically written into a file** in the application's folder. In other words, I just want to see the whole content of the XCode area debug into a text file.

I saw some code snippets but each of them **avoids the display into XCode** (that is unacceptable). I just want to duplicate the debug text to a file... Is there a way to do that ?

### **EDIT 1** (after trying the Clement's answer) :

I get a linker error :
[image]

### **EDIT 2** (how I have implemented the Clement's answer) :

I created a new class called ***LogHelper*** :

**LogHelper.h** :

```
#define NSLog(args...) _Log(@"DEBUG ", __FILE__,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,args);
@interface MyCustomLog : NSObject
void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...);
@end
```

**LogHelper.m** :

```
#import "LogHelper.h"

@implementation MyCustomLog : NSObject

void append(NSString *msg){
    // get path to Documents/somefile.txt
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myCustomLog.txt"];
    // create if needed
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
        fprintf(stderr,"Creating file at %s",[path UTF8String]);
        [[NSData data] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
    // append
    NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
    [handle writeData:[msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [handle closeFile];
}

void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, format);
    format = [format stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format] arguments:ap];
    va_end (ap);
    fprintf(stderr,"%s%50s:%3d - %s",[prefix UTF8String], funcName, lineNumber, [msg UTF8String]);
    append(msg);
}
@end
```

And I added `#import "LogHelper.h"` in `myApplication-Prefix.pch`.

### **EDIT 3** (I found a solution) :

- I set an environment variable called "runningFromXCode" ([follow this link to see how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17394454/2791407)) to keep the debug text showing into the console when the app is running from XCode ;
- I wrote this piece of code into the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379047/2791407)) :

  ```
  if (getenv("runningFromXCode") == NULL){
      NSArray *allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *pathForLog = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.txt"];

      freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
  }
  ```

Comment: You want it written to the app bundle during debugging?  bad idea; choose somewhere else.

Comment: But anyway `dup2()` is probably what you are looking for...

Comment: @trojanfoe you can't write to files in app bundle. It is read only because the bundle dir is code signed with SSL certificate

Comment: @Clement Where do I say you can do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NSLog(args...) _Log(@"DEBUG ", __FILE__,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,args);
    @interface MyCustomLog : NSObject
    void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...);
    @end

    @implementation MyCustomLog
    void append(NSString *msg){
        // get path to Documents/somefile.txt
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myCustomLog.txt"];
        // create if needed
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
            fprintf(stderr,"Creating file at %s",[path UTF8String]);
            [[NSData data] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        }
        // append
        NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
        [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
        [handle writeData:[msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [handle closeFile];
    }

    void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start (ap, format);
        format = [format stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format] arguments:ap];
        va_end (ap);
        fprintf(stderr,"%s%50s:%3d - %s",[prefix UTF8String], funcName, lineNumber, [msg UTF8String]);
        append(msg);
    }
    @end
```

[stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file)

Comment: This code is taken from the following question without attribution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for the link. I used it in a project but couldn't find the source. Answer is updated with attribution

Comment: @Erzékiel the same code works for me. Can you update ur question with how did you implement and use the MyCustomLog call?

Comment: @Clement Sorry for the delay, please see the edit 2.

Comment: @Erzékiel I checked ur code. There is nothing wrong in the code. I checked in iPhone & simulator. 
You just have to call NSLog(arg), in you classes. That what ur doing right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still having the two linkers errors (edit 1)... So I can't build with the `#import "LogHelper.h"`line into `myApplication-Prefix.pch`.
As you can see in the edit 1, the errors fired into `OrdoScanViewController`. it's a third party C++ library, and I spent several hours to integrate it, because it fired me similar linker errors...